# encfs error while decoding the data

Tags: encfs

I have installed encfs and started using it to secure all my personal & office data and it was working absolutely fine until 2 hours back. The setup is like this.

- I have a folder in Copy folder called OfficeData which gets synchronized with my Copy folder
- When I login into the system I use the command `encfs ~/Copy/OfficeData ~/Documents/OfficeData`
- Once my work is over I dismount with the command `fusermount -u ~/Documents/OfficeData`
- All this data get synchronized with my desktop and with my mobile phone (as a backup)

Today when I mounted, the folder got mounted by no directories and files present in that folder. I was worried and read `man encfs` which gave me to run the command `encfs -v -f ~/Copy/OfficeData ~/Documents/OfficeData 2> encfs-OfficeData-report.txt`. The below is the output of the file encfs-OfficeData-report.txt.

The directory "/home/sri/Documents/OfficeData" does not exist. Should it be created? (y,n) 
13:16:26 (main.cpp:523) Root directory: /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:26 (main.cpp:524) Fuse arguments: (fg) (threaded) (keyCheck) encfs /home/sri/Documents/OfficeData -f -s -o use_ino -o default_permissions 

13:16:26 (FileUtils.cpp:177) version = 20

13:16:26 (FileUtils.cpp:181) found new serialization format

13:16:26 (FileUtils.cpp:199) subVersion = 20100713

13:16:26 (Interface.cpp:165) checking if ssl/aes(3:0:2) implements ssl/aes(3:0:0)

13:16:26 (SSL_Cipher.cpp:370) allocated cipher ssl/aes, keySize 32, ivlength 16

13:16:26 (Interface.cpp:165) checking if ssl/aes(3:0:2) implements ssl/aes(3:0:0)

13:16:26 (SSL_Cipher.cpp:370) allocated cipher ssl/aes, keySize 32, ivlength 16

13:16:26 (FileUtils.cpp:1620) useStdin: 0

13:16:46 (Interface.cpp:165) checking if ssl/aes(3:0:2) implements ssl/aes(3:0:0)

13:16:46 (SSL_Cipher.cpp:370) allocated cipher ssl/aes, keySize 32, ivlength 16

13:16:49 (FileUtils.cpp:1628) cipher key size = 52

13:16:49 (Interface.cpp:165) checking if nameio/block(3:0:1) implements nameio/block(3:0:0)

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (RawFileIO.cpp:191) getAttr error on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/UWbT-M-UKk1JpvNfN5uvOhGn: No such file or directory

13:16:49 (CipherFileIO.cpp:105) in setIV, current IV = 0, new IV = 4188221457101129840, fileIV = 0

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/UWbT-M-UKk1JpvNfN5uvOhGn

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/UWbT-M-UKk1JpvNfN5uvOhGn

13:16:49 (RawFileIO.cpp:191) getAttr error on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/UWbT-M-UKk1JpvNfN5uvOhGn: No such file or directory

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:138) getattr error: No such file or directory

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (RawFileIO.cpp:191) getAttr error on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/o94olxB3orqarqyFviHKZ,ZF: No such file or directory

13:16:49 (CipherFileIO.cpp:105) in setIV, current IV = 0, new IV = 16725694203599486310, fileIV = 0

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/o94olxB3orqarqyFviHKZ,ZF

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/o94olxB3orqarqyFviHKZ,ZF

13:16:49 (RawFileIO.cpp:191) getAttr error on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/o94olxB3orqarqyFviHKZ,ZF: No such file or directory

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:138) getattr error: No such file or directory

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (RawFileIO.cpp:191) getAttr error on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/tVglci2rgp9o8qE-m9AvX6JNj1lQs-ER0OvnxfOb30Z,3,: No such file or directory

13:16:49 (CipherFileIO.cpp:105) in setIV, current IV = 0, new IV = 1354483141023495884, fileIV = 0

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/tVglci2rgp9o8qE-m9AvX6JNj1lQs-ER0OvnxfOb30Z,3,

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/tVglci2rgp9o8qE-m9AvX6JNj1lQs-ER0OvnxfOb30Z,3,

13:16:49 (RawFileIO.cpp:191) getAttr error on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/tVglci2rgp9o8qE-m9AvX6JNj1lQs-ER0OvnxfOb30Z,3,: No such file or directory

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:138) getattr error: No such file or directory

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (RawFileIO.cpp:191) getAttr error on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/r1KIEqVkz-,7-6CobavHCSNn: No such file or directory

13:16:49 (CipherFileIO.cpp:105) in setIV, current IV = 0, new IV = 16720606331386655431, fileIV = 0

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/r1KIEqVkz-,7-6CobavHCSNn

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/r1KIEqVkz-,7-6CobavHCSNn

13:16:49 (RawFileIO.cpp:191) getAttr error on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/r1KIEqVkz-,7-6CobavHCSNn: No such file or directory

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:138) getattr error: No such file or directory

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:16:49 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:16:49 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:16:49 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:16:49 (RawFileIO.cpp:191) getAttr error on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/r1KIEqVkz-,7-6CobavHCSNn: No such file or directory

13:16:49 (CipherFileIO.cpp:105) in setIV, current IV = 0, new IV = 16720606331386655431, fileIV = 0

13:16:49 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/r1KIEqVkz-,7-6CobavHCSNn

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/r1KIEqVkz-,7-6CobavHCSNn

13:16:49 (RawFileIO.cpp:191) getAttr error on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/r1KIEqVkz-,7-6CobavHCSNn: No such file or directory

13:16:49 (encfs.cpp:138) getattr error: No such file or directory

13:19:31 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:19:31 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:19:31 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:19:31 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:19:31 (encfs.cpp:685) doing statfs of /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData

13:19:32 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:19:32 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:19:32 (RawFileIO.cpp:191) getAttr error on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/LuT8R,DlpRnNH9b,fjWiKHKc: No such file or directory

13:19:32 (CipherFileIO.cpp:105) in setIV, current IV = 0, new IV = 13735228085838055696, fileIV = 0

13:19:32 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/LuT8R,DlpRnNH9b,fjWiKHKc

13:19:32 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/LuT8R,DlpRnNH9b,fjWiKHKc

13:19:32 (RawFileIO.cpp:191) getAttr error on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/LuT8R,DlpRnNH9b,fjWiKHKc: No such file or directory

13:19:32 (encfs.cpp:138) getattr error: No such file or directory

13:19:32 (encfs.cpp:685) doing statfs of /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData

13:19:32 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:19:32 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:19:32 (RawFileIO.cpp:191) getAttr error on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/UWbT-M-UKk1JpvNfN5uvOhGn: No such file or directory

13:19:32 (CipherFileIO.cpp:105) in setIV, current IV = 0, new IV = 4188221457101129840, fileIV = 0

13:19:32 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/UWbT-M-UKk1JpvNfN5uvOhGn

13:19:32 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/UWbT-M-UKk1JpvNfN5uvOhGn

13:19:32 (RawFileIO.cpp:191) getAttr error on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/UWbT-M-UKk1JpvNfN5uvOhGn: No such file or directory

13:19:32 (encfs.cpp:138) getattr error: No such file or directory

13:19:32 (MACFileIO.cpp:75) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0

13:19:32 (FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)

13:19:32 (RawFileIO.cpp:191) getAttr error on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/o94olxB3orqarqyFviHKZ,ZF: No such file or directory

13:19:32 (CipherFileIO.cpp:105) in setIV, current IV = 0, new IV = 16725694203599486310, fileIV = 0

13:19:32 (DirNode.cpp:770) created FileNode for /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/o94olxB3orqarqyFviHKZ,ZF

13:19:32 (encfs.cpp:134) getattr /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/o94olxB3orqarqyFviHKZ,ZF

13:19:32 (RawFileIO.cpp:191) getAttr error on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/o94olxB3orqarqyFviHKZ,ZF: No such file or directory

13:19:32 (encfs.cpp:138) getattr error: No such file or directory

13:19:32 (encfs.cpp:213) getdir on /home/sri/Copy/OfficeData/

13:19:32 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 208, 16, -192

13:19:32 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: eWJrLh2dRFAY-7Brbsc,mTqf

13:19:32 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml

13:19:32 (BlockNameIO.cpp:185) padding, _bx, finalSize = 218, 16, -202

13:19:32 (DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: pvph9DkZ0BMPg2vN4UcfwuNU

13:24:10 (openssl.cpp:48) Allocating 41 locks for OpenSSL

Please help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for info on similar errors, probably too late to help but maybe useful for others?

I just tried making a new encfs directory, added a dozen files, moved and deleted a couple files, then unmounted. And on re-mounting it then I got similar errors to some of yours:

There's always the `(DirNode.cpp:132) error decoding filename: .encfs6.xml` where it tries to decode the config .encfs6.xml file, and then it listed a few `getattr error No such file or directory` errors for files that just weren't there. I don't know why but I suspect it's got something to do with the filename encryption, causing it to look for files that aren't there anymore? Maybe you've got some programs trying to read the files that are supposed to be there & generating errors?

You've also got several `(FileNode.cpp:127) calling setIV on (null)` errors at the start, I didn't try the external IV chaining so maybe it's normal?

fyi- Also when trying to access (ex. cat) a file that doesn't exist in the un-encrypted directory it will give an "getattr error No such file or directory" with an encrypted filename that's apparently created on-the-fly, and then afterwards checked for an existing file to decrypt. I suppose it's more secure that way, where the alternative would be keeping a decrypted list of all files in ram.

Anyway, here's what I'd try:

1. Stop syncing with your phone in case your phone's backup is still good & your desktop files have become corrupted. Or maybe the syncing is what corrupted them. And make a backup copy of the Desktop's files in case they're good & it's encfs that's the problem & something you try messes them up. Only work on copies of files, good data recovery practice "just in case".
2. Try a fsck on your drive in case it's going bad, maybe even a reboot (works for windoze, couldn't hurt?)
3. Manually create the directory "/home/sri/Documents/OfficeData" just in case something went wrong there, log had "...does not exist. Should it be created? (y,n)"
4. Try using a backup copy of the .encfs6.xml file & see if it works. I'd try the phone's backup first, and if not then a known good copy from a separate non-sync'd "frozen" backup.
5. If still bad, try a full backup copy & see if it works. If yes, then can try  copying the files changed since the backup, one at a time, and see if they can now be read. The file attributes look the same on the encrypted files and the decrypted files (at least in my files)
6. If nothing's worked, try un-install & re-install of encfs itself, or look for an updated version of encfs to try. Speaking of which maybe your system updated encfs and now the newer version can't decrypt your files... Or try from a live disk of ubuntu, a live disk from a different computer even if the files are worth the effort?

For the future, I'd keep frequent known good backups somewhere too, not only sync'd since it could sync corruption & get ruined. Maybe unencrypted or saved with a different encryption, like a tarball | gpg -c ? Data recovery & encryption are usually at odds with each other.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Xen2050. I still kept the original copies as it is. I stopped syncing when I encountered the first corruption. I will your suggestions and see if that works.